# Android SDK HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk, scrollview

This is the layout of my app, I will want both the album and the songs (Red & Blue) to move horizontally as you scroll to view different albums (Purple).  However, I want the songs (Blue) to move independently vertically to scroll through the songs in the album.

So far my coding looks as you would expect...

```
<LinearLayout
   <HorizontalScrollView
       <LinearLayout
           <LinearLayout (This layout is so the album cover is displayed correctly)
               <ImageView
               <ScrollView
                 <LinearLayout
                     <TextView   (Songs)
                     <TextView
                     <TextView
                     <TextView
```

My problem occurs when I vertically scroll through the songs.  when I scroll vertically, if I move my finger to the left or the right it detects the HorizontalScrollView and stops scrolling vertically.  What can I do to stop this?  If there is nothing I can do, what else except HorizontalScrollView could I use?

Thanks,

-Steven

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say fundamentally you need to change your layout. First off, each album will have a different number of songs, so the list of songs would be best done as a `ListView` as opposed to hand built `ScrollView`. Next, for the album, I would use a `ViewPager` and attach a `ViewPager#OnPageChangeListener` to it and when the page is changed the list of songs are updated.
Now to fix your current xml, and based on my understanding that you **only** want the Album to be moving left to right you need to do this:

```
<LinearLayout
   <HorizontalScrollView
       <LinearLayout
           <LinearLayout (This layout is so the album cover is displayed correctly)
               <ImageView
   </HorizontalScrollView> <!-- end the album HSV here --!>
               <ScrollView
                 <LinearLayout
                     <TextView   (Songs)
                     <TextView
                     <TextView
                     <TextView
               </ScrollView>
```

Whats happening is you are wrapping the vertical `ScrollView` in your `HorizantleScrollView` for no reason. Now if you would like some level of left/right tug that would cause the next whole page to show up - I would switch to the `ViewPager`. (If you aren't sure what I mean here, look at Google Play. They have vertical `ListViews` and you can pull left and right for new pages...

Comment: Thank you... as you can tell I am new to the java/android SDK,
ViewPages is a much better option then the scroll views

Comment: No worries! To use `ViewPager` you are going to need the Android Support JAR: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html Also since this is the path you want read about `ListView` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html